# Search from Array with custom fields Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search

I have an arrays

```
var searchArray = [(
    ean: String,
    name: String,
    weight: String,
    brand: String,
    percent: String,
    inside: String,
    img: String,
    packet: String,
    date: String)
    ]()

var searchArrayFiltered = [(
    ean: String,
    name: String,
    weight: String,
    brand: String,
    percent: String,
    inside: String,
    img: String,
    packet: String,
    date: String)
    ]()
```

I have a code for search from arrays and show result in table:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchArrayFiltered = searchText.isEmpty ? searchArray : searchArray.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
        return dataString.(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But in line `return dataString.String(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil` i have an error:

> Value of tuple type '(ean: String, name: String, weight: String,
>   brand: String, percent: String, inside: String, img: String, packet:
>   String, date: String)' has no member 'String'

If I change dataString.String to dataString.name, I have an error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'

Please help me to do search from `searchArray` for **"name"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are discouraged from using a tuple as array type. Use a custom struct or class

Apple says:

> Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They’re not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.

---

There are two major issues:

1. Copy&Paste mistake, you mean `dataString.range(of...`
2. `dataString` is not a string, it's a tuple (the type annotation is redundant)

Change the function to

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchArrayFiltered = searchText.isEmpty ? searchArray : searchArray.filter({tuple -> Bool in
        return tuple.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm always working with java\android, and swift for me is Hell.

Answer (score 0):

create a struct for

```
struct Model {
    var ean: String
    var name: String
    var weight: String
    var brand: String
    var percent: String
    var inside: String
    var img: String
    var packet: String
    var date: String
}
```

then apply filter on your `[Model]`